# Using libarchive in python on Windows

Tags: python, windows, libarchive

I'm trying to get libarchive module working in python 3.4 on windows.
I've installed libarchive-c with pip and all went ok but whenever I try to import it into my code or even to run it alone I'me getting error:

```
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

This is coming from ffi.py from the code below:

```
libarchive_path = os.environ.get('LIBARCHIVE') or find_library('archive') 
libarchive = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(libarchive_path)
```

I've never used ctypes before but if I understand correctly it is looking for external DLL. So found and installed http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libarchive.htm also I've added C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin to my %PATH% in environmental variables but it still cannot load the module. As it does not give me the name I'm not sure what module it is looking for.
What am I missing?

Comment: It's looking for either the DLL name from the `LIBARCHIVE` environment variable or "archive.dll". I suggest using `LIBARCHIVE` instead of renaming the DLL. You can test this in the command prompt using `set LIBARCHIVE=libarchive2.dll` before running Python. Note that this is a 32-bit DLL, so you'll have to use 32-bit Python.

Answer (score 6):

(disclaimer) I contribute to https://github.com/Changaco/python-libarchive-c and I maintain https://github.com/nexB/scancode-toolkit

Both contain a `ctypes` binding for `libarchive`, though ScanCode is for extraction only.

My answer here is for `python-libarchive-c`, but ScanCode contains some of the DLL you are looking for so I am lacing in a bit of both.

To get `python-libarchive-c` going on Windows you need a `libarchive` DLL and its deps that can then be loaded.

There are no pre-built DLLs bundled in `python-libarchive-c` but I have prebuilt Windows binaries for another project here:
https://github.com/nexB/scancode-toolkit/tree/develop/src/extractcode/bin/win-32/bin
The corresponding source code is there: https://github.com/nexB/scancode-thirdparty-src
And you have `MinGW32` build instructions there if you want to rebuild from source yourself: https://github.com/nexB/scancode-thirdparty-src/blob/master/libarchive/build.sh#L47

In general to load a DLL from a path -- assuming that the var `libarchive` contains the full path to that DLL -- use this:

`lib = ctypes.CDLL(libarchive)`

Now this is for Scancode. For `python-libarchive-c`, you could try to set the `LIBARCHIVE` variable to point the path of your DLL with:
`set LIBARCHIVE="C:\.....\libarchive.dll"`

Then start Python, import the library and use it.

NB: I did not test this (yet) , but this should work. IF not please file a bug.
I did not run any test on Python 3.4 either. I use primarily Python 2.7.
But the DLL and the code is not Python 2.7-specific at all.

FWIW, the way scancode loads the library is a tad more engaged since it can from the same code load DLLs Win/Linux/Mac for specific 32 or 64 bits archs using conventional locations. You can see the code in action there:
https://github.com/nexB/scancode-toolkit/blob/develop/src/extractcode/libarchive2.py#L64

ScanCode is NOT using `python-libarchive-c` ATM yet but a different/custom ctypes binding focused on a more specific use case of extraction only. At least it gives you access to a Win DLL and its deps (or instruction a build them) and an example on how to load it correctly.

/HTH

Comment: ***I*** tried it, but the libarchive module still will not find the libarchive.DLL  - even though I set LIBARCHIVE variable in cmd.exe

Comment: I had to change the code in the module: `if _FILEPATH == '':
    _FILEPATH = ctypes.util.find_library('libarchive')
    if _FILEPATH is None:
        _FILEPATH = 'libarchive.dll'` <-- *to* ***.dll*** *instead of* ***.so***

Comment: Besides, this seems to work under windows without patching (but we still need the DLLs of course) https://github.com/Changaco/python-libarchive-c