# Error while loading libarchive in windows - Library can not be loaded: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, dll, pip, tar, libarchive

I am a beginner in python,trying to install "Libarchive",  in a windows 10 64-bit laptop, am using python 3.7 getting following error

```
$ pip install libarchive
Collecting libarchive
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bf/d4/26f5c9835d4d648e4f22b5fb91288457698e928aaf9d4ab7eff405b7ef03/libarchive-0.4.7.tar.gz

Requirement already satisfied: nose in c:\users\jyo27\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from libarchive) (1.3.7)

Installing collected packages: libarchive

Running setup.py install for libarchive: started

Running setup.py install for libarchive: finished with status 'error'

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\users\jyo27\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\jyo27\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9ria1jtc\libarchive\setup.py'"'"'; file='"'"'C:\Users\jyo27\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9ria1jtc\libarchive\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(file);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\jyo27\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-qcjbgrm0\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
cwd: C:\Users\jyo27\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9ria1jtc\libarchive

Complete output (4 lines):

running install

error: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
Verifying that the library is accessible.
Library can not be loaded: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\jyo27\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\jyo27\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9ria1jtc\libarchive\setup.py'"'"'; file='"'"'C:\Users\jyo27\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9ria1jtc\libarchive\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(file);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\jyo27\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-qcjbgrm0\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Please format that output properly, it's difficult to read. Are you using virtual environments?

Comment: can you refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37173863/2825570)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using libarchive in python on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37165002/using-libarchive-in-python-on-windows)

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Thanks for suggestion, i have formatted the error. I did not use virtual environment. I tried to "pip install libarchive" in git bash.

Comment: @Jyothsnajyo Is git involved in this?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile no, i used git bash terminal, libarchive installation failed in windows terminal as well

Comment: A question on a similar question suggest that conda might be less prone to this kind of issue on Windows. Could you try using Conda, at least just to test the installation of this particular library?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile It is showing the same error in anaconda prompt too. I think this a linux package as it worked on linux os but not in windows. can you suggest me any alternative package for libarchive for windows please?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem but can't find the answer yet.